# Excel VBA inquiry regarding find a specific word, inserting a row, and pasting into said row

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String
Dim del1 As Variant

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set InputFile = ActiveWorkbook
        Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open("\\SHKFS1\Shared\MONAHAN\1st watch files\inst status sheet\STATUSSHEETINSTITUTIONAL.xlsm")
        del1 = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value
        If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                OutputFile.Sheets("UI").Cells.Find(del1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                OutputFile.Sheets("UI").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 2) = Target.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 2).Value
                OutputFile.Sheets("UI").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 3) = Target.Value
                OutputFile.Sheets("UI").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "Monahan"
            End If
            OutputFile.Close savechanges:=True
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to find the word “UI” and insert a row below it and paste the information above(after the “Else” in the code) into that row that was inserted. Same thing would be for the “LOP”.

UI

Beam, Jim 123456

Jones, Jim 123456

LOP

Davis, Betty 456789

Crack, Donald 456789

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is good for making your code run faster without screen flicker. It's a nightmare when your code isn't working properly. Comment it out until things work right. What is your code doing or not doing? Are you getting an error? Help us help you.

Comment: Also, you only need `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` one time in there (you've got it twice), and your `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` is conditional - if you don't get into that first `If`, you'll leave `ScreenUpdating` turned off. move it to just before the `End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

you may be after this:

```
        ...
        Else
            Dim f As Range
            With OutputFile.Sheets("UI")
                Set f = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:="UI", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            End With
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                f.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                f.Offset(1).Resize(, 3) = Array(Target.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 2).Value, Target.Value, "Monahan")
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
        ...
```

Comment: @EricMiller, did you get through it?